# C++ string equivalent for strrchr

Tags: c++, std

Using C strings I would write the following code to get the file name from a file path:

```
#include <string.h>

const char* filePath = "dir1\\dir2\\filename"; // example
// extract file name (including extension)
const char* fileName = strrchr(progPath, '\\');
if (fileName)
  ++fileName;
else
  fileName = filePath;
```

How to do the same with C++ strings? (i.e. using `std::string` from `#include <string>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest equivalent is [`rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind):

```
#include <string>

std::string filePath = "dir1\\dir2\\filename"; // example
// extract file name (including extension)
std::string::size_type filePos = filePath.rfind('\\');
if (filePos != std::string::npos)
  ++filePos;
else
  filePos = 0;
std::string fileName = filePath.substr(filePos);
```

Note that `rfind` returns an index into the string (or `npos`), not a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

To find the last occurence of a symbol in a string use [`std::string::rfind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/)

```
std::string filename = "dir1\\dir2\\filename"; 
std::size_t pos = filename.rfind( "\\" );
```

However, if you're handling filenames and pathes more often, have a look at [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

```
boost::filesystem::path p("dir1\\dir2\\filename");
std::string filename = p.filename().generic_string(); //or maybe p.filename().native();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either call `string::rfind()`, or call `std::find` using reverse iterators (which are returned from `string::rbegin()` and `string::rend()`).

`find` might be a little bit more efficient since it explicitly says that you're looking for a matching character. `rfind()` looks for a substring and you'd give it a length 1 string, so it finds the same thing.

Comment: There is `rfind` overload that accepts a char instead of string, so your note does not seem to be right.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `rfind()`, you can also use `find_last_of()`
You have an example too written in [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) which is same as your requirement.