# Extract the file name from filename with path which comes from argument

Tags: c++, string

My program get the filename with or without path(direct or indirect).
I'd like to use the filename from argv as a part of output filename.
The problem is that sometimes the filename from argv includes path and sometimes doesn't.

What I want to do is
1. if filename includes path, extract filename only and return filename.
2. if filename doesn't includes path, return filename.

Current my code is

```
  std::string input_trace_filename = argv[1];
  std::string read_filename = input_trace_filename + ".read.";
  std::string write_filename = input_trace_filename + ".write.";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Any spaces in your filenames?

Comment: Look for the last slash, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254728/c-string-equivalent-for-strrchr).

Comment: Looks like you want [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) and its [`path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) class. Or if your compiler is new enough to have [`std::filesystem::path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) (from the upcoming C++17 standard) then use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
std::string filename = string(argv[1]);
int index = filename.find_last_of("/\\");
std::string input_trace_filename = filename.substr(index+1);
```

Comment: Maybe check for both in Windows? Remember that forward slash `/` is a valid path separator in Windows too (has been since the MS-DOS days actually).

Comment: `/` is valid in Windows for web addresses but not local pathsno? anyway as mentioned just try it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, perhaps ideally, one should find both indexes and use the larger one.

Comment: @user2079303: Yes, updated to cover all possible scenarios.